# GitLab Error nothing to commit, working tree clean

Tags: git, gitlab

I joined the private gitlab project and set up global.user etc.

```
$ git clone "git url"
```

I successfully modified the code and I did not add or delete any files.

So I ran an additional command

```
$ git add.
$ git commit -m "Edit ServerURL"
```

However, this code did not work with errors.

> On branch master
>
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin / master'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Until I participated in the project, there was only one participant, and the branch seems to have only one master.
What should I do?

Comment: git add command should be `git add .` and not `git add.` There needs to be space between add and '.'

Did you try it this way?

Comment: I tried it right away, but $ git: 'add.' is not a git command.
Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my comment. Please check if you added space between 'add' and '.'

Otherwise your command looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

> GitLab Project Homepage -> Settings -> Repository -> Protected Branches

I gave it permission and it worked.